# WordPress: Remove "plugins_loaded" hooked action executed by a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action, wordpress-hook

I need to remove the following action executed by a plugin:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart');
```

That is all things that I have tried so far *(without success)*:**

1.) I tried adding this to my theme's functions.php as well as to a plugin I created (but it didn't work):

```
remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart');
```

2.) I have created a plugin and also a function, and added this to it:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_unwanted_code');
function remove_unwanted_code(){
    remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart');
}
```

3.) I also tried adding a later priority like so:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_unwanted_code');
function remove_unwanted_code(){
    remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_variable_product_add_to_cart', 31);
}
```

Nothing works for instance. What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: It can be useful? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223652/remove-action-from-plugin-on-other-plugin/256605

Comment: Try to use `init` hook on `remove_unwanted_code()` function instead on your 2nd code.

Comment: @Vdgaetano thank you but I already tried everything on that link

Comment: @LoicTheAztec doesn't work

Comment: @Shtarley The provided information in your question is not enough to get people able to help you more than that… You should edit your question providing more details (what plugin? what php file? what Class? what does handle remove_variable_product_add_to_cart() function?) and showing more code context… Note that  *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**."*

Comment: you can also try to set a lower or a higher priority in your 2nd code snippet like: `add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_unwanted_code', 1 );` or `add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_unwanted_code', 100 );`…